# C compile error with makefile

Tags: makefile

I have written a program in c and I am using a make file within cygwin on windows to compile the file. Execution is perfectly fine within Visual Studio, however when I try using my make file, the following occurs:

**Error:**

```
$ make
gcc    -c -o mathTable.o mathTable.c
mathTable.c:1:1: error: stray ‘\377’ in program
 ▒▒# i n c l u d e   < s t d l i b . h >
 ^
mathTable.c:1:2: error: stray ‘\376’ in program
 ▒▒# i n c l u d e   < s t d l i b . h >
  ^
mathTable.c:1:3: error: stray ‘#’ in program
 ▒▒# i n c l u d e   < s t d l i b . h >
   ^
mathTable.c:1:4: warning: null character(s) ignored
 ▒▒# i n c l u d e   < s t d l i b . h >
    ^
mathTable.c:1:6: warning: null character(s) ignored
 ▒▒# i n c l u d e   < s t d l i b . h >
      ^
mathTable.c:1:5: error: unknown type name ‘i’
 ▒▒# i n c l u d e   < s t d l i b . h >
     ^
...
...
...
mathTable.c:73:21: warning: null character(s) ignored
mathTable.c:73:25: warning: null character(s) ignored
mathTable.c:73:27: warning: null character(s) ignored
mathTable.c:74:1: warning: null character(s) ignored
mathTable.c:75:1: warning: null character(s) ignored
mathTable.c:75:3: warning: null character(s) ignored
mathTable.c:76:1: warning: null character(s) ignored
mathTable.c:77:1: warning: null character(s) ignored
mathTable.c:78:1: warning: null character(s) ignored
mathTable.c:79:1: warning: null character(s) ignored
make: *** [<builtin>: mathTable.o] Error 1
```

I am starting to study C so I am not quite sure what could be causing this. It seems bizarre. Maybe something to do with Linux? as I am not handling cross platform (since I didn't think I needed to).

Comment: @TobySpeight I have edited the post so that it is now hopefully helpful in the future.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you can improve that Makefile by adding two lines: `.DELETE_ON_ERROR:` and `.PHONY: all clean`.

Comment: This would be better if you remove all traces of the "Makefile"

Comment: This error also shown in my project. Visual Studio adds that hidden character. See my [chat message](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/43207659#43207659). +1 for sharing this issue as Q&A.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is likely because your file has Windows UTF-16 format. Maybe it contains strings or comments in your native language. Visual C++ compiler understands this, but GCC (Mingw) does not. Save your file in UTF-8 format without marker.

Answer (score 7):

This is not a GNU Make error.

The compiler complains that your source file encoding is wrong. You need to use ASCII or UTF-8 with `gcc` compiler.

Or try `-finput-charset=UTF-16` compiler option.